# Differentiation under expectation $f(x)=E[|x-Y|].$

Tags: integration, statistics

Let $Y$ be a random variable with zero points mass which is integrable. Let x be in $[-M,M]$ for some $m\in\mathbb{r}$. Consider
$$f(x)=E[|x-Y|].$$
I want to take the derivative of $f(x)$ in a point $x_0\in(-M,M)$. Here is my attempt of a solution. Using dominated convergence with majorant $|Y|+|M|$, and that $Y$ has zero point mass in $x_0$ I obtain that
$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0+h)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}E[\frac{|x_0-Y|-|x_0+h-Y|}{h}]=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}E[\frac{|x_0-Y|-|x_0+h-Y|}{h}1_{Y\not=x_0}]=E[\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x_0-Y|-|x_0+h-Y|}{h}]=E[-1_{x_0-Y<0}+1_{x_0-Y>0}]=2P(Y\leq x_0)-1.$$
Is the above argument correct hence in the above setting it is correct that $f'(x_0)=2P(Y\leq x_0)-1$? And if it is correct doesn't it also hold in general that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(-M,M)$

I have tried for $U$ uniform([0,1]) and $x_0\in(0,1)$ where i get $E[|x-U|]=x^2-x+1/2$ which differentiated is $2x-1$ which is equal to $2P(U\leq x)-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^{\infty}\mathsf{P}(|x-Y|\ge t)\, dt \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^x\mathsf{P}(Y\le t)\, dt+\int_x^{\infty}\mathsf{P}(Y\ge t)\, dt.
\end{align}
Thus, if $\mathsf{P}(Y=x)=0$,
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\mathsf{P}(Y\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y\ge x) \\
&=2\mathsf{P}(Y\le x)-1.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and you time d.k.o.